# Is there a way to set logon time restrictions via group policy?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, group-policy

Rather than setting logon time restrictions on each user account, we would like to apply it via group policy to a security group. Is this possible?

Note that I am asking to set the restriction times in one location for many users, not for the policy setting that enables the enforcement of the restriction times.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you need.

This shows how to restrict the hours and days that a user may log on to a Windows Server 2003 domain (can't find the win2k8 at the moment, but it shouldn't be too different)

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816666

--

Nathan, I'd like to add, you would apply the GPO enforcement per security group. Your security group would contain the computers in a particular location. This would effectively control time restrictions via enforcement on computers in that particular location. You would need to create multiple GPO per location.

Comment: I've added some clarification to my question. That article does not say how to set the time in one location for a group of users.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a native method to do so. I wrote a [package](https://sourceforge.net/projects/trbdk3netlogoff/) a few years ago that includes a script to so however.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple via GPO.  In Server 2003 it was simple as noted by @ColdT.  I do not have a 2008 system in front of me but should be similar

This article[Logon Options](http://blogs.technet.com/b/grouppolicy/archive/2006/10/04/windows-logon-options_3a00_-part-two-of-two.aspx) can help.

Comment: I've added some clarification to my question. That article does not say how to set the time in one location for a group of users.